# C++/MFC fail to login websit using HTTPS

Tags: c++, visual-c++, https, mfc

```
i use fiddler capture the POST message ,the different between normal login(firefox)    
and mine is only the content-length:
(fireFox)Content-Length: 164
(mine) Content-Length: 165
i dont think it's the problem.
Then,i find that HTTPS connection to(Tunnel to Packet) server is more different.
i just show the difference.
Here is the message:
```

1. fireFox:
    - Headers: ;
      * CONNECT account.xiaomi.com:443 HTTP/1.1;
      * Host: account.xiaomi.com ;
    - CONTENT:
      * Version: 3.2 (TLS/1.1)
      * Ciphers: have more than 30 items;
2. mine):
    - Headers:;
      * CONNECT account.xiaomi.com:443 HTTP/1.0;
      * Host: account.xiaomi.com:443;
    - CONTENT:
      * Version: 3.1 (TLS/1.0)
      * Ciphers: have 12 items
i use CHttpFile to post

Comment: Re: the difference in `Content-Length`. You are including the terminating NUL character in the data sent. You shouldn't. Drop +1 in `_tcslen(szRequest)+1`.

Comment: thank you so much.Now,i can login the website using Post. but why the NUL causing fail.

Comment: Why shouldn't it? What makes you believe you can just go ahead and append arbitrary data to the end of a request without negatively affecting its behavior?